# Removing a value from an Arrays.toString();?

Tags: java, arrays, string, ascii

So, the goal is to have the user give a string, then the console gives back the characters in the string and their frequency.

The input "AAAAbbbbccdd 42424242 &&%%$#@" (minus the quotes) should give...

freq: 2

.# freq: 1

$ freq: 1

% freq: 2

& freq: 2

2 freq: 4

4 freq: 4

@ freq: 1

A freq: 4

b freq: 4

c freq: 2

d freq: 2

They should also be sorted alphabetically according to the ASCII table, but I'm not concerned about that right now.

This is the code I have for my method:

```
    public static void alphabeticalSort(String input)
{
    int[] ascii = new int[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char current = input.charAt(i);
        ascii[(int)current]++;
    }

    String asciiStr = Arrays.toString(ascii).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "\n freq:");
    System.out.println(asciiStr);

}
```

I won't paste the output here for the sake of space, but the output will read back every element of the 256 element array and tell me that the character appeared 0 times. Is there any way to make all the 0 occurrence characters to not be displayed when I print out the string?

Comment: Use a loop instead of hoping Arrays.toString() will do the work for you.

Comment: `ascii = Arrays.stream(ascii).filter(x -> x > 0).toArray();`

Comment: Your code doesn't actually say what it's reporting the frequency *of*, though. It just says `freq: 0\nfreq: 2`.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to try to figure that out by myself before bothering people again. I'm not really sure how, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply filter out elements from the array, based on the value:

```
ascii = Arrays.stream(ascii).filter(x -> x > 0).toArray();
```

But this isn't very much use: you lose the correspondence between the frequencies and the characters that they are the frequency of.

Instead, filter a stream of indexes:

```
IntStream.range(0, ascii.length).filter(x -> ascii[x] > 0)
```

This stream gives you the indexes of elements in the array which have non-zero values.

You can use this in building your output:

```
System.out.println(
    IntStream.range(0, ascii.length)
        .filter(x -> ascii[x] > 0)
        .mapToObj(x -> String.format("%s: freq %s", (char) x, ascii[x]))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Comment: Oh my, thank you! This worked perfectly, somehow. I'm unfamiliar with how this method works. So does the .filter just ensure that values > 0 are printed? I'm not entirely sure what "%s" does, or really how the syntax of the .mapToObj works. But the .collect is essentially just how the printed elements are separated when printed? In this case, a new line?

Comment: `%s` is just a token in a string which will have something substituted in. You could also write that line `.mapToObj(x -> (char) x + ": freq " + ascii[x])`, if that's any easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in another solution using `Collectors` functions from the `stream` api:

```
String string = "AAAAbbbbccdd 42424242 &&%%$#@";

String result = Arrays.stream(string.split(""))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " freq: " + entry.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```